# How to add Native dll in monodevelop as I am trying to build a webService using some native dll

Tags: mono, monodevelop

System.Exception: SimpleLPR2_native.dll not found. Check that the contents of the 'native' folder is accessible. In case it weren't please copy the full contents of the 'native' folder to the same directory where SimpleLPR2.dll is located in your application. Depending on the project configuration Visual Studio can make a local copy of referenced assemblies, in that case you should also copy the 'native' folder there. The 'native' folder in the SDK can be found in [PROGRAM FILES]\Warelogic\SimpleLPR 2.2\bin
  at SimpleLPR2.Shimmy.setup () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the native dlls to the project and make sure the "copy to output directory" is checked in the "quick properties" in the context menu.